# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'split' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LBPB6/52/) there is a `To` button.When clicked on this button,a dialog box appears.By default from the select menu `users` is selected.If I select a check box from this users table and after that If change the drop down menu to groups and from the select a checkbox from groups table then `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'split' of undefined` appears in the consolse.However from the beginning(without selecting any checkbox of users table) If i change to groups table and then select some checkbox then the above error does not appear.Can any body please tell me how to solve this issue.

The following is the jquery code

```
$('#ViewFull').click(function () {
    $('#mytable1 tr').removeClass('hide');
});
$('.select').on('change', function () {
    var tablink = '#' + $(this).val();
    $('#groups').hide();
    $('#users').hide();
    $(tablink).show();
});

function copy_users_table() {
    var users = $('#mytable').html();
    $('#mytable12').html(users);
}

function copy_groups_table() {
    var groups = $('#TogroupsTable').html();
    $('#groupsTable1').html(groups);
}

function collect_users_and_groups(is_groups) {
    var tos = [];
    $('#mytable12 input:checked, #groupsTable1 input:checked').each(function (i, elt) {
        //alert("to groups");
        if (is_groups) {
            //alert("to groups");
            var dataids = $(this).parent().attr("data-selected").split(",");
            alert("dataids  " + dataids);
        }
        var name = $.trim($(this).parent().next().text());
        tos.push(name);
    });

    return tos.join(', ');
}

$('body').on('click', '#to-btn', function () {
    // copy current tables
    copy_users_table();
    copy_groups_table();

    // initialize checkboxes
    var number = $('#number').val();
    $('#ToAdd').text(number);
    var entries = number.split(/\s*,\s*/);
    init_users_table(entries);
    init_groups_table(entries);

    $("#mytable12 input:checkbox").on('change', function () {
        var tos = collect_users_and_groups(false);
        $("#ToAdd").html(tos);
    });

    $("#groupsTable1 input:checkbox").on('change', function () {
        var tos = collect_users_and_groups(true);
        $("#ToAdd").html(tos);
    });

    // show tab
    $('.select').val('users');
    $('#users').show();
    $('#groups').hide();
});

$('#ToOk').click(function () {
    $("#number").val($("#ToAdd").text());
});

function init_users_table(entries) {
    // go through all rows
    $('#users tr').each(function () {
        var username = $('td:nth-child(2)', this).text();
        var selected = $.inArray(username, entries) >= 0;
        $('input:checkbox', this).prop('checked', selected);
    });
}

function init_groups_table(entries) {
    $('#groups tr').each(function () { //added 13
        var groupname = $.trim($('td:nth-child(2)', this).text());
        var selected = $.inArray(groupname, entries) >= 0;
        $('input:checkbox', this).prop('checked', selected);
    });
}
```

Comment: Probably `$(this).parent().attr("data-selected")` is undefined

Comment: @Satpal I guess it's `undefined`.

Comment: @Satpal But how it is undefined.After selecting checkbox of users only this error come

Comment: That's what error says mate.

Comment: @Satpal not getting how to solve,any  idea?

Comment: In `collect_users_ang_groups` you iterate over checked checkboxes for both users and groups, but for user checkboxes you do not have `data-selected` attribute defined in HTML - only for group checkboxes. It is easy to investigate if you use debugger or just output `this` and `this.parent().attr("data-selected")` to the console in that method.

Comment: @GRaAL in function `collect_users_ang_groups` I have `if (is_groups) {` so If the group is selected then only `var dataids = $(this).parent().attr("data-selected").split(",");
            alert("dataids  " + dataids);` is called.Please see the line 28 in js section of the fiddle

Comment: Yes, it is called when you check the group checkbox, but it is called for both user and group checkboxes - this `$('#mytable12 input:checked, #groupsTable1 input:checked')` iterates on both. Just put the breakpoint inside and you'll see for which elements it is called.

Comment: @GRaAL I am very new to jquery,even I dont know how to put breakpoints and debugging.But thanks for help

Comment: Oh, I see. If you use chrome you may check [this reference](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging?hl=ru). The simplest way to debug your apps is to use `console.log(variable-or-string)` and check javascript console (Ctrl+Shift+J in Chrome for Windows) for output. In your sample you may add a line like `console.log(this, $(this).parent(), $(this).parent().attr('data-selected')` and then you'd see for each click on group checkbox what your method is called for. Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, when you make a call to the 'collect_users_and_groups' function, the code is executing for both checked checkboxes that belong to #mytable12 and checked checkboxes belonging to #groupsTable1 (due to the selector on which you apply each).
Even if you call the function with is_groups = false, the code will still go through this snippet for the checkboxes previously selected in #mytable12:

```
if (is_groups) 
{
    //alert("to groups");
    var dataids = $(this).parent().attr("data-selected").split(",");
    alert("dataids  " + dataids);
}
```

So, if you previously checked a checkbox in #mytable12, the code will return undefined for $(this).parent().attr("data-selected"), because there is no such attribute for these kind of table cells.

Change your code the following way:

```
$('#mytable12 input:checked').each(function (i, elt)
{
    var name2 = $.trim($(this).parent().next().text());
    tos.push(name2);
});
$('#groupsTable1 input:checked').each(function (i, elt) {
    //alert("to groups");
    if (is_groups) {
        //alert("to groups");
        var dataids = $(this).parent().attr("data-selected").split(",");
        alert("dataids  " + dataids);
    }
    var name = $.trim($(this).parent().next().text());
    tos.push(name);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answering.Can you please give me a working fiddle?

Comment: You are genious man.Can you please tell me which lines you have changed so that it will be easy for me to change in my app,+1 for help.

Comment: $('#mytable12 input:checked, #groupsTable1 input:checked').each(...) this is the one you need to split in 2.